# Table with fixed header - tbody overflows thead in my table

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to have a fix header in my table and I managed halfway through. Indeed, I can scroll the content but the `tbody` overflow the `thead`. I found many questions on stackoverflow and I tried many of them but without success...

**UPDATED**
And with the margin-top, the `tbody` appears in the margin-top when I scroll

Here is my code:

```css
.fixed-header {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}

table {
  color: black;
  max-height: 750px;
  margin-top: 31px;
  width: 100%;
}

thead {
  background-color: #505d66;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 31px;
}

tbody {
  background-color: grey;
}

tbody tr td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-header">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>COL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You set `position: sticky` on the `th`, not the `thead`, but have the background color on the `thead`. Since that's not sticky, it scrolls away.

Comment: Yes because I remove it the header is not fixed anymore

Comment: move the background color to `th`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @acesmndr said, just put the background color on the TH

```css
.fixed-header {
  margin-top: 30px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 250px;
}

table {
  color: black;
  max-height: 750px;
  width: 100%;
}

thead {
  background-color: #505d66;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #505d66;
}

tbody {
  background-color: grey;
}

tbody tr td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-header">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>COL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ITEM</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I reproduce it in my code but I forgot to add a margin-top. I updated my post. With the margin-top the table jumps to the top when I scroll @cclar413

Comment: @PierBJX I'm not sure I am following, can you please explain?

Comment: In fact, I have a margin-top in the table element and when I scroll, the tbody appears in the margin-top. If you run again my code snipper you will understand. @cclark413